# Any tips for improving Visual Studio 2008 ASP.NET designer performance?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, performance, asp.net-2.0

It's been bugging me for a while now, but the ASP.NET designer in VS 2008 can be terribly slow for editing even the simplest of pages. The machines we use are not bleeding edge, but one would think that a 2Ghz Dual Core AMD 3800+ with 3Gb of RAM and a 7200RPM 120Gb hard drive would perform better than it does.

To quantify the problem, opening the design view for a page with a 3-5 of textboxes, a dropdown, and a DataGrid may take 30-45 seconds ... or longer. Really complex screens can sometimes take several minutes to open. And once open, the designer is very sluggish - clicking on a control can take a couple of seconds to take effect. The properties window doesn't always update correctly. Right-click menus can take several seconds to appear.

We've tried defragmenting our drives, killing unnecessary processes, upgrading to SP1, and even re-installing the development environment but the problem still persists.

Has anyone else out there observed similar performance issues, and if so, does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve the performance? For example, are there any IDE features we could turn off (i.e. intellisense) that might help out? If you aren't seeing any issues I would be curious to know what specs (CPU, RAM, HD) your machines are configured with.

EDIT: Some additional facts and corrections. First, a quick correction, we in fact have 7200RPM drives from Western Digital, not 5200 RPM models.

Second, based on some investigation into where the bottlenecks are, when the designer is loading it seems like there is a lot of dead time - < 20% CPU, just a bit of I/O wait. But the overall effect is very slow.

We do use Resharper in our projects, but disabling this add-on does not perceptibly improve the performance of the designer.

Comment: That sounds like yet another great reason to not use the designer...

Comment: You need to look at what is taking the time. Is the CPU time spiking? Do you have other add-ins loaded (like ReSharper)? Is the memory usage and/or paging increasing when you enter the designer (or when you click)?

Comment: If you're seeing dead time, check the network.

Comment: I don't use the designer and I still have the same problems - when I open a page, the IDE freezes. When I go to type something in the page, the IDE freezes. 

I don't know what VS2008 is doing, but it's not CPU or IO bound - I'd say it's just crappy implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/01/tip-trick-hard-drive-speed-and-visual-studio-performance.aspx) that ScottGu posted on visual studio performance. I think it may be geared more towards 2005, but it's worth a look.

In general I'd recommend not using the designer...

Answer (score 0):

The only real bottleneck you have is the HDD. Nowadays a 5200RPM drive is a bit slow to be on development machine.